# Tornado Session Inactive Expiry

Tags: python, tornado

The session should be expired automatically if the user is inactive for a certain time interval. How can I achieve this in tornado?

Comment: You need to keep track of when the user was last active. Maybe keep a timestamp of it somewhere and later just check if this timestamp is older than a certain amount of hours, then invalidate the session.

Comment: @xyres You mean to keep details of session in a JSON or any databases like Redis?